# Passthrough whole SATA Controller to Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am a bit confused about perfomance virtual drives based physically on SSD. 
It is no matter - or it's raw mode or virtual image disk mode. All SSDs goodies are nearly gone (((
There are tones of bad stories about this on googled...

Now I am wondering if its possible to passthrough whole SATA IDE controller from Linux host to Windows guest. Hope that way can help me to get native SSD perfomance or not?

```
lspci | grep -i 'sata\|sas'
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
05:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 02)
```

Both IDE controllers are free, because I use only LSI on host. It would be a good option to passthrough one of them to Windows guest.

I have Intel 5520 chipset (with VT-d support, L5630 Xeon and 3.19.0-59-generic kernel).

Will this work?

Comment: Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html and find in page `To add a SATA controller`. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Make sure Host Caching is checked in VirtualBox.

Comment: Alex, I am speaking about real (not virtual) controller. Of course I know that it's possible to add virtual controllers, and off course, Daniel B, I know what is "host caching". I would like to figure out, is it possible for me to passthrough physical sata ide controller)))

Answer (score 0):

Unlike qemu/kvm in Linux, VirtualBox does not support PCIe passthrough (i.e. making use of VT-d / the IOMMU). So no, you can't passthrough your SATA controller to your VM.

Even if it does, your host system will need to be installed on a non-SATA drive (unless you have two or more SATA controllers, not ports, in your system).

There will also be considerable overhead in solutions like `vfio-pci` or `pci-stub` in qemu/kvm, so you won't really get "native" performance either. (IIRC, the overhead was even higher than solutions like `virtio-scsi` or `virtio-blk`.)

Comment: Not supported???? What about this https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough

Comment: I have two controllers on host, LSI scsi (with raid volumes had host system installed) and sata ide (afaik, chipset integrated). All ports of sata ide not used, so I am free to do anything with it...

Comment: Hmm, apparently Oracle added that to its extension pack recently. Well so you've found the documentation, just follow it if you want to try?

Comment: I have only one (production) server with that options... It's not a good idea to make experiments on it)))

Comment: So, I am tried to passtrough chipset SATA Controller, but no luck, because of controller using shared IRQ (https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=56568), in my case there USB, . So for now it's closed... Will see if I get discrete PCI SATA Controller to put it into PCI-E slot on motherboard and try it to passthrough to VBox...